# Reverse a list of string without affecting numeric values

Tags: python

I have a list of strings.

```
arr = ['17 -> 16 -> 1 -> 8 -> 0', '5 -> 2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 0']
```

I want to reverse the string, for which I am using this code:

```
x = arr[::-1]
x = x.replace(">-", "->")
x = x[5:]
```

But the output is:

```
arr = ['0 -> 8 -> 1 -> 61 -> 71', '0 -> 6 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5']
```

Whereas, I need the output to be:

```
arr = ['0 -> 8 -> 1 -> 16 -> 17', '0 -> 6 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5']
```

Comment: Why do you `.replace(">-", "->")`? The `arr[::-1]` is ignored, since `x` is ignored in the rest of the program.

Comment: Edited the code. My bad!!

Answer (score 6):

You should split your strings on the arrow characters, reverse, then join them back. This works:

```
[' -> '.join(reversed(a.split(' -> '))) for a in arr]
```

Comment: Extremely minor implementation detail note: Given `str.join` `list`-ifies the input when it's not a `list` or `tuple`, the lazy features of `reversed` don't help here, and the overhead of calling it and converting the result back to `list` hurts; `[' -> '.join(a.split(' -> ')[::-1]) for a in arr]` would get the same results, and (in local tests) takes about 30% less time to run (at least on my 64 bit CPython 3.6 install). Upvoted regardless; either version is perfectly Pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`:

```
arr = ['17 -> 16 -> 1 -> 8 -> 0', '5 -> 2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 0']
final_list = list(map(lambda x:' -> '.join(x.split(' -> ')[::-1]), arr))
```

Output:

```
['0 -> 8 -> 1 -> 16 -> 17', '0 -> 6 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5']
```

Comment: Even if the performance issues have been overcome in Python3, seeing `map` or `filter` molested with a `lambda` function gives me the creeps.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: The performance issues weren't "overcome" in Python 3 in any event (it just made them lazy, so you have fewer temporaries when the results need to be something other than a `list`). `map`/`filter` with a non-C-level-builtin callback function call is always slower than an equivalent listcomp/genexpr that can inline the work (avoiding the function call overhead entirely). Since any use of an inline `lambda` is definitionally inlinable, the equivalent non-`lambda` listcomp/genexpr always wins (and is usually shorter/more readable to boot).

Answer (score 1):

The basics are split the string by spaces, reverse it, then stick it back together again.

```
" ".join(reversed("1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5".split()))
```

then for each one just do

```
for a in arr:
    print(" ".join(reversed(a.split())))
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, `regex` based for extracting the numbers from string:

```
>>> arr = ['17 -> 16 -> 1 -> 8 -> 0', '5 -> 2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 0']

>>> [' -> '.join(re.findall('\d+', a)[::-1]) for a in arr]
['0 -> 8 -> 1 -> 16 -> 17', '0 -> 6 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5']
```

This is **helpful incase the pattern between the numbers varies**.

---

Also, a slightly different version of [*Daniel's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48063855/2063361) without using `reverse` as:

```
#                                 v  to reverse the list
>>> [' -> '.join(a.split(' -> ')[::-1]) for a in arr]
['0 -> 8 -> 1 -> 16 -> 17', '0 -> 6 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

`[x.split(" -> ")[::-1] for x in arr]` splits the string into sub-lists of strings at `->` and reverses them using a list comprehension

The `" -> ".join(..)`  joins the inner lists back to a string

```
arr = ['17 -> 16 -> 1 -> 8 -> 0', '5 -> 2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 0']

sub = [" -> ".join(x.split(" -> ")[::-1]) for x in arr]

print(sub)
```

Output

```
['0 -> 8 -> 1 -> 16 -> 17', '0 -> 6 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5']
```

---

Edited: removed overly complicated stripping and adapted split-text after seeing [Daniel Rosemans split pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48063855/7505395).

```
# sub = [" -> ".join([y.strip() for y in x.split("->")[::-1]]) for x in arr]
```